# FirebaseUI Sign-In Not Working with Proguard After Gradle and Java version Updates

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, firebaseui

I'm encountering an issue while using sign-in functionality in my Android app with [FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) .Initially, it was working correctly with Proguard enabled. However, after making some version changes in my code, it has stopped working when Proguard is enabled. Specifically, I'm not receiving any results in the onSignInResult callback during the sign-in flow. Strangely, when I disable Proguard, the sign-in process works as expected.Before these changes its worked fine with both proguard enabled and disabled,but after these changes it only works fine with proguard disabled.

Changed

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2.1-bin.zip
```

Changed

```
gradle version "7.2.0"
```

to

```
gradle version "8.0.2"
```

Changed

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

Added

```
namespace Application.id
```

inside android block of build.gradle

Changed

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
```

to

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
```

Importantly, I haven't made any changes to my Proguard file, which I've shared below:

```
-keep class com.xyz.business.domain.model.* { *;}
-keep class com.xyz.framework.dataSource.cache.database.* { *;}
-keep class com.xyz.framework.dataSource.cache.model.* { *;}
-keep class com.xyz.framework.dataSource.network.model.* { *;}
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable        # Keep file names and line numbers.
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception  # Optional: Keep custom exceptions.
```

I have attempted to address the issue by adding the following lines to my Proguard file, but they haven't resolved the problem:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
# Firebase UI Auth
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

# Only necessary if you downloaded the SDK jar directly instead of from maven.
-keep class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding following lines to my proguard file fix this issue:

```
-keep public class com.google.firebase.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
```

Reference: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2124#issuecomment-920922929